# Configuring JBoss EPA 6.1 with IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, jboss6.x, jca

I am developing a service for JMS messaging using IBM WMQ version 7.5 as Message oriented middleware. I am in a dilemma. The IBM specification says to use WebSphere MQ JMS API in JAVA EE environment. My sender and receivers will be in remote JBoss deployments. IBM provides a resource adapter to connect via JCA. This connection requires static administration of components such as Queue managers, queue channels, queue names.

Is JCA the best I can do ? Is there any other way where I can dynamically create the queues provided that I know other configuration details ? There will be multiple applications using this setup running on their own servers. If I use JCA, all have to make their own configurations. Can I make dynamic configurations ?

Answer (score 1):

Typically within the application server environment resources would be created in some JNDI context. These would be Connection Factories and Destinations.

Depending on the app server, it may be possible to share this configuration across a network of individual servers.  So typically there would be some set of static definitions.

However within say a servlet the MQConnectionFactory can be dynamically created.

In all cases the backing WMQ Resources do need to exist; though it is possible to send administrative command messages to WMQ to create queues and do other admin. The only exception is topics, accessing a topic string brings it into existence. Though this has default security properties that you might not want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer much appreciated. I don't want to connect via servlet using MQConnectionFactory as it won't have all the features like connection pooling etc. I was able to make this work in my system using JCA but yes static definitions are required.